# Advice on speeding up prime number counter

Tags: java, loops

How can I improve the logic of the following code? The purpose is to compute the number of primes from 1 to the user input (limitNo). The program works fine except it takes a while, more than the usual 1-3 secs, to generate a result for huge numbers like 99999.

```
public static int countPrime(int limitNo) {
  int noOfTimes = 0, noOfRounds = 0; int o = 1;
    
  while (o <= limitNo) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= o; i++) {
      if (o%i == 0) {
        noOfRounds++;
      }        
    }   
    if (noOfRounds == 2) {
      noOfTimes++;
    }
    noOfRounds = 0;    
    o++;
  }
    
  return noOfTimes;
}
```

Comment: What _kind_ of runtime error does it run into? Can you add the error message to your question?

Comment: Take a look at the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Runtime error refers to the program taking more than the usual (1-3 secs) to generate an output

Comment: This is fundamentally a math question, not a programming question. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889712/the-fastest-way-to-count-prime-number-that-smaller-or-equal-n

Answer (score 1):

The code can be improved by

1. Separating some of the lines to make an `isPrime()` method.
2. Changing limits of the `for` loop so that if the condition is met that means the number is not prime.

   ```
   public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
     for ( int i = 2 ; i < num ; i++ ) {
       if ( num % i == 0 ) {
         return false;
       }
     }
     return true;
   }
   ```
3. Replacing the code in the method with `isPrime()` and change the start `int o = 2 ;`.

   ```
   public static int countPrime(int limitNo) {
     int noOfTimes = 0;
     int o = 2;
     while ( o <= limitNo ) {
       if ( isPrime(o) ) {
         noOfTimes++;
       }
       o++;
     }
     return noOfTimes;
   }
   ```
4. Of course, there are better and more improvements like:

   ```
   for ( int i = 2 ; i <= num/2 ; i++ )
   ```

   ```
   for ( int i = 2 ; i <= Math.sqrt(num) ; i++ )
   ```